# NFS Shared Folders - Is it transitive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

If I have Computer-A, and share a folder to be accessed by Computer-B, can I take that same shared folder and share it with Computer-C?

Computer-B has two itnerface cards, eth0, and eth1. eth0 is connected on the same network as Computer-A, and eth1 is connected on an alternate network that Computer C.

Computer-B is on both networks.

### Computer-A <--> Computer B <--> Computer C

Platform: Ubuntu 10.04

Thanks

-Manny

Comment: What version of NFS are you using?

Comment: **someuser@somewhere:/usr/include/nfs$ rpcinfo -p localhost | grep -i nfs**    
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs  
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs  
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs  
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs  
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs  
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs

Answer (score 2):

You cannot re-export a mounted NFS filesystem, second-hand, because Computer B doesn't have authority to export that filesystem again.  Not to mention the problems you could have with locking, and stale nfs handles.

There is a userland nfs server, uNFS, that can share just about anything, including re-exporting mounted NFS filesystems, however it specifically says that results should be considered unreliable.

You're really better off having Computer A share to both B and C

```
Computer A --> Computer B
          \
           --> Computer C
```

Answer (score 0):

One janky alternative could be to share the NFS mount via CIFS.  This worked for my use-case, but I wouldn't recommend it for critical applications.  I'm also doing it read-only - pretty sure locking could get weird if you're trying to do writes or if there are multiple concurrent users.  On Debian it would go something like this:

On the server that's re-sharing the NFS export:

```
# Mount your NFS share:
$ mount -t nfs 1.2.3.4:/my/export /mnt/ex
# Set up samba config - something like this:
$ tail -n7 /etc/samba/smb.conf
[backups]
  path = /mnt/ex
  browsable = yes
  read only = no
  guest ok = yes
  follow symlinks = yes
  wide links = yes
# Install samba server:
$ apt install samba
```

Now on your client you can mount the NFS share via CIFS:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //4.3.2.1/backups /mnt/backups
```